# Two diodes in input stage of power amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier, power-amplifier

Some of the power amplifier schematics include diodes in input stage like below. What is the purpose of them?

[image]

Comment: They are being used as voltage clamps, most probably.

Comment: @Chi But how do that work?

Comment: It stops the input amplitude from exceeding one diode drop of voltage,  some amplifier designs misbehave badly with too much input signal.

Comment: No inputs shown. No outputs shown, No power rails shown. This circuit has no context at all.

Comment: What don't you understand in this diodes?

Comment: @G36 Since the collector of Q19 cannot exceed one diode drop above the bottom rail, D6 can only ensure that the collector of Q12 doesn't go below that rail. That "concern" doesn't make much sense to me. Though I see no harm in D6, I'm also not sure why it is there. (Perhaps this is a discrete circuit and someone might "short" that node?) D5, on the other hand, makes abundant sense to me, as protecting the base voltage to Q8 is a good safety measure.

Comment: @jonk "Normally" this "ant-saturation" diodes are used in slightly different "current mirror" and the VAS configuration.  See the example https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/3351737400_1517336557.png

Comment: @G36 Yes, I see it there. Just this one I'm not as certain about the need, is all. But okay. It certainly doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @jonk I don't see on schematic how the D5 protects base voltage of Q8, may you give more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collector of \$Q_{19}\$ cannot be more than a diode drop above the bottom rail, because its base is tied to the collector. \$D_5\$ then prevents the collector of \$Q_{12}\$ from being more than two diode drops above the bottom rail. Since the \$Q_6\$ (I was wrong to write \$Q_8\$ before, in comments) base is tied there too, this prevents the base of \$Q_6\$ from being hauled up more than two diode drops above its emitter. That shouldn't be a problem in a well designed circuit. But it might help limit things in unplanned abusive situations with the circuit.

I wasn't quite as sure of \$D_6\$ before. But \$Q_{19}\$ and \$Q_{12}\$ do form up a mirror. Normally, a design (and the DC portion of the feedback from the output) will arrange things so that a slight voltage imbalance (a minor DC "tilt") at the bases of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ supply the needed base current for the \$Q_6\$ VAS (which has to sink all the remaining current left over from the \$Q_5\$ source.) The applied signal will normally swing the base of \$Q_1\$ around a bit and this will vary the current *squirted* into the base of \$Q_6\$. This difference current shouldn't be leaving from the collector side of \$Q_2\$. But in the oddball case where it is (such as at certain frequencies where the phase delay causes positive feedback and the whole thing isn't working as it should), \$D_6\$ might then make sense as a path to allow the mirror and the diff-pair to continue functioning in this crazy situation. Normally, you don't design things so that you squirt out the current from the leg that is tied to the diode-connected mirror BJT. But I can imagine extreme cases where you'd figure adding this diode path makes some sense.

---

Actually, I'd be happy to hear the input (and criticism) of my betters here. I'm just a hobbyist and in cases where I've done something like this myself, I didn't bother with these diodes and everything was just fine. But that doesn't mean they aren't a good idea for making a circuit more bullet-proof. I may not be fully aware of the possible thinking here. But that's my take.

Comment: You wrote "which has to sink all the remaining current left over from the Q5 source". May be not source, may be an emmiter, as Q5 isn't a FET?

Comment: @MaxMil I meant "source" in a different way. There are current sinks and current sources. And these have nothing in particular to do with a source or drain of a FET (though FETs can also be used to produce current sources and current sinks.)

Comment: @jonk. Long speech for a +1. I like the *squirted* parts. They are just overdrive clamps.

Comment: @Sparky256 Yeah. But if I just called them that the OP wouldn't have a picture in their head. I tried to paint a small image of sorts. I like to think of the diff-pair as a teeter-totter that shifts current between collectors based on base voltage difference. Adding the current mirror forces both collectors to have the same current. It's kind of like "the irresistible force meets the immovable object" and the only solution is for an "escape path" provided through which the difference current is "squirted out." Makes for an easy image, anyway.

Comment: @jonk. Ok... Squirt away. lol.